# unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes' with XOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, xor

I asked this question before it's closed as a duplicate I tried the duplicate link but nothing work.

the full code:

```
import requests
import base64
import urllib.parse
import operator




username = "badministrator"
password = "Password1"
URL = "http://url/login.php"
values = {'username' : username, 'password' : password}

def first_login(url_login, value):
    with requests.Session() as c:
        c.post(url_login, data = value)
        response = c.get(url_login, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
        Cookie = [value for key,value in c.cookies.get_dict().items()]
        cookie, IV = Cookie
        return cookie, IV

def base64_decode():
    cookie, IV = first_login(URL, values)
    decode_cookie = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(cookie))
    decode_IV = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(IV))
    return decode_cookie, decode_IV

def xor_exp():
    decoded_cookie, decoded_IV = base64_decode()
    decoded_IV[0] = bytes(map(operator.xor, b'a', b'b', decoded_IV[0]))
    decoded_cookie[0] = b'a'
    return decoded_IV, decoded_cookie


print(xor_exp())
```

I can't iterate in bytes or xor three bites together

Comment: there is no `^` operator for working with strings(or bytes) ....  `^` is for integers ...

Comment: how can I xor bytes? need it to build a cypher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytes` are immutable, so if you want to change their contents, you either can construct a new `bytes` object (like you would do with strings or tuples) or create a `bytearray`. I'll show them both, below:

```
def xor_exp():
    decoded_cookie, decoded_IV = base64_decode()
    decoded_IV = bytes([3 ^ decoded_IV[0]]) + decoded_IV[1:]
    decoded_cookie = b'a' + decoded_cookie[1:]
    return decoded_IV, decoded_cookie
```

```
def xor_exp():
    decoded_cookie, decoded_IV = base64_decode()
    decoded_cookie = bytearray(decoded_cookie)
    decoded_IV = bytearray(decoded_IV)
    decoded_IV[0] = 3 ^ decoded_IV[0]
    decoded_cookie[:1] = b'a'
    return bytes(decoded_IV), bytes(decoded_cookie)
```

---

Attempt 2:

If you know the `bytes` objects will only contain a single character, I would simply call `ord` on them:

```
decoded_IV[0] = ord(b'a') ^ ord(b'b') ^ decoded_IV[0]
```

Which, given these specific values is equal to

```
decoded_IV[0] = 3 ^ decoded_IV[0]
```

---

Attempt 1:

You can not directly xor `bytes` objects in Python, but you can xor `int` objects, and `bytes` implement `Iterable[int]`, which means you can do:

```
import operator

...

decoded_IV[0] = bytes(map(operator.xor, b'a', b'b', decoded_IV[0]))
```

This uses the standard library function [`operator.xor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) and the builtin function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: I tried that also gave an error ```TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize `decoded_IV[0]` was an integer. I think I understand now. Will update.

Comment: decoded_IV is base64 decode result base64 return as bytes IDK what the issue.
base64 function:

```
def base64_decode():
 cookie, IV = first_login(URL, values)
 decode_cookie = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(cookie))
 decode_IV = base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(IV))
 return decode_cookie, decode_IV
```

Comment: Wait, `decoded_IV` is of type `bytes`? Those are immutable, you need to either create a new object or create a `bytearray`.

Comment: If `isinstance(var, bytes)` then `isinstance(var[0], int)`, which is what makes my old answer work for arguments that are all `bytes`.

Comment: `decoded_IV[0] = bytes(map(operator.xor, b'a', b'b', decoded_IV[0]))`
`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: also with the updated answer shown this error:
`TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Please update the question with information about `base64_decode()`, either with a link to the library it's from or its implementation, as well as if `b'a'` and `b'b'` are truly constants or just examples. I gave you two wrong answers because I didn't have enough information and make some assumptions about your program that turned out to be false, so please help me give you the right answer!

Comment: sorry for that, I added the full code you can check it.thank you

Comment: This should be the final version! If you don't want to hard-code the `3`, you can replace it with `ord(b'a') ^ ord(b'b')` like in my second attempt.